# Unity 3D How to smoothly transition between animations so that it doesn't automatically go back to 'idle'?

Tags: unity-game-engine

The character starts with an 'idle' animation. When direction.magnitude is greater than 0 it goes to 'walk' animation. When I press the shift key it goes to the 'sprint' animation. My problem is that when it has to go from 'walk' to 'sprint' it doesn't do it directly walk->sprint only walk->idle->sprint. This causes an unsightly effect when the animation transitions.

How to smoothly transition between animations so that it doesn't automatically go back to 'idle'?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Fscj.jpg)

My animator settings:

Idle to Walk (walk is true)
Walk to Idle (walk is false)
Walk to Sprint (sprint is true)
Sprint to Walk (sprint is false)
Idle to Sprint (sprint is true)
Sprint to Idle (sprint is false)

Comment: Have you thought about using [blend trees](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-BlendTree.html)? Make sprint not its own state, but instead make a "move" blend tree that blends between the two. Then, you essentially have the state "move" and "speed" and use speed to toggle between "walk" and "sprint".

Answer (score 0):

When only one state should be at a time regarding something (in this case the movement animation), I like to use only one variable for it to avoid situations where for example walk and run is both true, or walk false and run is true, etc.

Make an int "State" parameter in the animator, and create the transitions like

- idle -> walk if State == 1
- idle -> run if State == 2
- walk -> idle if State == 0
- walk -> run if State == 2
- run -> idle if State == 0
- run -> walk if State == 1

On the code side, create an enum for better readability:

```
private enum AnimState
{
    Idle,
    Walk,
    Run
}
```

And you just need to set the state in the script, something like this (half-pseudo-code):

```
if (move)
{
    if (shift_down) _animator.SetInt("State", (int)AnimState.Run);
    else _animator.SetInt("State", (int)AnimState.Walk);
}
else _animator.SetInt("State", (int)AnimState.Idle);
```